# Localising a WPF application doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, globalization

I must be missing something here.

I create a brand new WPF application in VS2015. I create a resource 'String1' and set the value to 'fksdlfdskfs'.

I update the default MainWindow.xaml.cs so that the constructor has:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Title = Properties.Resources.String1;
    }
```

And run the application, and it works fine, my window title is fksdlfdskfs.

In the AssemblyInfo.cs file I see the below comments:

```
//In order to begin building localizable applications, set 
//<UICulture>CultureYouAreCodingWith</UICulture> in your .csproj file
//inside a <PropertyGroup>.  For example, if you are using US english
//in your source files, set the <UICulture> to en-US.  Then uncomment
//the NeutralResourceLanguage attribute below.  Update the "en-US" in
//the line below to match the UICulture setting in the project file.

//[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

So I add the following into my WpfApplication5.csproj file and reload the project in VS:

`<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>`

And then uncommented the following line in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

If I now go to run the application, the application no longer runs and I get the following exception on the line where I read the resource:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any
>   resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
>   culture.  Make sure
>   "WpfApplication5.Properties.Resources.en-US.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "WpfApplication5" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

If I change `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite` to `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly` in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, I get the following exception instead:

> System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not forced to use code behind for localization, you can simply use `x:Static` markup extension to bind to static fields:

```xml
<Window
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:SandBox.Properties"
    Title="{x:Static properties:Resources.TitleSandbox}">

</Window>
```

Just make sure your Resource file access modifier is set to Public

[image: Screen resource file]

The error message you get typically means you do not have a `Resource.en-US.resx` file because `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]` is here to tell your app to use en en-US resource file as default source. 
Add a file named `Resources.en-US.resx` if you want to get rid of the error the quick way

What I personally do to localize a WPF app is :

- I leave `AssemblyInfo.cs` as it is, which means that `Resource.resx` (without language id) file will be the default (which is generally en-US)
- I create additional `Resource.{id}.resx` file next to default like this : 
  [image: sample],

  It is usually the same as `Resource.resx` but translated in the matching language
- I force the culture at startup (typically in the `App.xaml.cs`) with a user settable language id so user can change application language :

```cs
// language is typically "en", "fr" and so on
var culture = new CultureInfo(language);
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
// You'll need to restart the app if you do this after application init
```

Comment: This is the easiest and most basic approach but the largest caveat is that the app needs to be restarted. There are some other alternative approaches to remedy that but then in those ways your interface strings are not visible in development window (since they are dynamic). I think there was a library called wpflocalizationextension which made things way easier.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for the guidance. Follow-up question then, is it possible to create/edit the resources for each language outside of Visual Studio or do I need to compile each language in like this? I see that becoming a pain when we have 20+ languages and each country sends their translations in at different times!

Comment: Sure! I myself use ResXResourceManager (https://github.com/tom-englert/ResXResourceManager) as it gives better edition abilities in Visual Studio (list all files and all language in one table for instance). There's also a dedicated client to edit resx files without VS, you can also export/import excel files

Comment: Misread your question: You are forced (unless an hack exists) to compile your project with the updated resx files in order to integrate additional languages, those are compiled in a different dll named {namespace}.{assembly}.resources.dll in a separate folder.

Comment: @Uwy use Microsoft MAT: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit

Comment: @juFo Care to explain what is it and why is it better than using multiple resx files ?

Comment: you still use multiple resx files but by using MAT use use xlf files (international standard for translations). it allows you also to manage your translations better. give it a try and you'll see ;-)

Comment: I'll give it a try when I'll be working on smaller projects, thanks !